# Copy file data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have used shutil to copy file content from one to another. But the already stored content in the second file is get removed. Is there any way to keep the already stored data and paste the new data at the last of the file.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand your problem in detail, if you upload your code.

Comment: You will have to write the file contents yourself. `shutil` gives you access to operating system services, and there isn't one for this task.

Comment: upload ur code and explain a little more